# Avoiding a copy constructor call when returning the constructed object by value in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class without a copy constructor, which I still want to return by value. The following MCVE compiles in C++17:

```
class Cls {
    public:
    Cls(int x) {}
    Cls(const Cls& c) = delete;
};

Cls f(int x) {
    return Cls(x);
}

int main() {
    f(0);
}
```

but not in C++11:

```
$ g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11
prog.cc: In function 'Cls f(int)':
prog.cc:9:17: error: use of deleted function 'Cls::Cls(const Cls&)'
    9 |     return Cls(x);
      |                 ^
prog.cc:5:5: note: declared here
    5 |     Cls(const Cls& c) = delete;
      |     ^~~
```

As I understand it, the reason is that the compiler is allowed *not* to optimize the copy out, even if it should be trivial in this case.

I was hoping `return std::move(Cls(x));` would work and avoid the copy constructor, but it gives the same error.

Can I fix the problem without defining the copy constructor (or the assigment operator)?

I've looked through related questions, but couldn't find a duplicate.

Comment: Even if the copy could be elided by the compiler (and thus no actual copy-ctor is called), a copy constructor is required. You explicitely disallow copying your type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it, the reason is that the compiler is allowed not to optimize the copy out, even if it should be trivial in this case.

That's correct.

> I was hoping return std::move(Cls(x)); would work and avoid the copy constructor, but it gives the same error.

This is no solution. `std::move(Cls(x));` won't do anything, as `Cls(x)` already yields a *prvalue*. Casting return values to rvalues should be done in rare cases, e.g. when returning a function parameter. Besides, a `Cls` rvalue can only be used without copying if you can move-construct another instance from this rvalue, which is not the case in your original snippet.

> Can I fix the problem without defining the copy constructor (or the assigment operator)?

You can define a move constructor instead as suggested by [@Matthieur Brucher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54476272/9593596). This enables returning a temporary object of type `Cls`, while still disallowing copying. You call that a move-only type, and one of the prominent standard types that is move-only is a `std::unique_ptr`.

As a final note, I think it's good practice to follow [C.21](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-default-operation-define-or-delete-them-all), which suggests handling move-construction/assignment and not to rely on the implicit deletion of these special member functions.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a move constructor instead.

In C++17, the compiler must do [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and may not have to copy or move the object. But for C++11, you don't have this facility, but you have the move for your case:

```
Cls(Cls&& c) = default;
```

Comment: "*in C++17, the compiler can do*" - the compiler is actually *required* to.

Comment: @Fureeish yes indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I fix the problem without defining the copy constructor (or the assigment operator)?

There are 2 options in your case:

- Define move constructor:

  ```
  Cls(Cls&& c) = default;
  ```
- Use [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which allows to not call copy/move constructor, it requires a non-explicit constructor:

  ```
  Cls f(int x) {
      return {x};
  }
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b88b3fed1fb1eb14)

In C++17, you have "guaranty" copy-elision (or "unmaterialized value passing"), so `return Cls(x);` would be fine.